# Как подставить значение переменной в нужном месте файла-шаблона?

Tags: html, bash

С помощью команды stat получаю сведения о последнем изменении файла, которые записываются в файл FileTimeChenge

```
stat --format=%z ~/Price > FileTimeChenge
```

С помощью mutt осуществляю рассылку пользователем с вложением файла

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=«Content-Type» content=«text/html; charset=utf-8»>
</head>
<body>
<p><font ><em><strong>Здравствуйте!</strong></em></font></p>
<p>Файл изменён - "Тут должна быть дата"</p>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите, как вставить в html код данные из файла - FileTimeChenge

По совету пользователя @aleksandr barakin удалось получить вывод переменной при конкатенации

```
cat body | envsubst '${Test}'
```

Но, при выполнении цикла mutt в теле письма отображается переменная, а не значение переменной

```
for I in `cat list`; do cat body |envsubst '${Test}' | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -a "/var/log/mail.log" -s "Title" -- $I < body;echo $I;sleep 3 ;done
```

Comment: в заголовке: «о создании», в тексте: «об изменении». уточните, пожалуйста. это существенно ввиду того, что далеко не во всех файловых системах сохраняется информация о дате создания файла.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin по сути, я слишком подробно описал. Мне всего лишь надо вставить в html код строку из файла, которая выглядит как - 
2020-06-29 14:44:28

Comment: открыть файл, считать нужные данные в переменную, вставить в текст в нужном месте. Готово. С чем именно проблемы? Можно даже и не сохранять в файл, а сразу в переменную.

Comment: @Эникейщик По Вашему совету, я получил переменную из вывода команды, Проблема в том,  что у меня не получается вставить эту переменную в html4 код.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сохраняете содержимое файла в переменную и экспортируете её:

```
$ export soderzhimoe=$(cat файл)
```

а для подстановки значений переменных используете, например, программу *envsubst* из пакета *gnu/gettext*:

```
$ cat файл.хтмл
<p>Файл изменён - "${soderzhimoe}"</p>
$ cat файл.хтмл | envsubst '${soderzhimoe}'
<p>Файл изменён - "то что было в 'файл'"</p>
```

аргумент с перечислением переменных для подстановки не обязателен, но лучше использовать его для безопасности — на случай, если в тексте у вас будут употреблены строки, похожие на обращения к существующим переменным окружения.

---

#### дополнение про ошибку:

вот в этом фрагменте:

> ```
> envsubst '${Test}' | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -a "/var/log/mail.log" -s "Title" -- $I < body
> ```

у вас получается конструкция: `программа1 | программа2 < файл`, т.е. программа2 получает на *stdin* содержимое файла, а не вывод программы1. уберите чтение из файла, вот этот кусок: `< body`.

Comment: cat файл.хтмл | envsubst '${soderzhimoe}' прекрасно отрабатывает, но если вставить в цикл mutt то на выходе получаю не значение переменной, а саму переменную:  for I in `cat list`; do cat body |envsubst '${Test}' | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -a "/var/log/mail.log" -s "Title" -- $I < body;echo $I;sleep 3 ;done

Comment: форматированный текст лучше вставлять в вопрос, а не в комментарий: здесь он нечитабелен.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы очень помогли.

Comment: к слову: если всем отсылается письмо одинакового содержимого, то можно одним вызовом программы mutt, без цикла, отправить письмо всем адресатам сразу.